# Hibernate : C3p0 pool configuration slowing down entire server.

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, c3p0

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which we are using Hibernate and c3p0 for Database transactions and connection pooling. Most of the time it works really good, no issues. But in certain situations I have to copy a lot of objects and files in the current transaction. When that happens, the entire server slows down and finally I start getting `could not rollback exception` . Anything wrong with my c3p0 settings? Thank you.

pom.xml :

```
 <!--- Hibernate dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

root-context.xml :

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
            destroy-method="close">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <beans:property name="url"
                    value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:PORT/DB_NAME"/>
    <beans:property name="username" value="USERNAME"/>
    <beans:property name="password" value="PASSWORD"/>
    <beans:property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
    <beans:property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="20"/>
    <beans:property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false"/>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
<beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.ourapp.spring.model"/>
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</beans:prop>
               <!--<beans:prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">1000</beans:prop>-->
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="cache.use_query_cache">true</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="show_sql">false</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">750</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">1000</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">150</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1200</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">auto</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>

</beans:bean>
```

Thank you.

Comment: The point here is to know that c3p0 isn't really able to handle large amount of data, which leads to slow servers and errors such as the one you describe. When you have such troubles, then you either need to try and optimize your query, or you need to switch to native SQL queries

Comment: @DamCx : There are multiple queries as a lot of information is required from DB. All of these queries are used on a regular basis without any trouble.

Comment: I can't comment on the configuration, but have you tried swapping out C3PO for something like Hikari? https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP

Comment: How did you determine that it's C3P0 that is to blame?

Comment: @WeareBorg are they used separately or always together? You might wanna check this, and maybe make some benchmarking about the load of data your queries and server are able to handle.

Comment: @DamCx : Okay, Any idea how to do that? I am checking out Hikari. It looks good. WIll try out locally first...

Comment: @Kayaman : Just by monitoring process status over top, no memory leak detected on a testing server. And rollback exceptions which many other users have is problem related to c3p0.

Comment: @WeareBorg try executing your queries on different amounts of data, while monitoring your server's "vitals" (Memory, response time), until you find when it has too much to process. Does your testing server have the same amount of data to process?

Comment: Using `top` isn't very suitable for profiling a Java process. While you may observe that there aren't any actual memory leaks, you don't know anything about the memory usage patterns.

Comment: @Kayaman : Okay. I will look for some java profilers which can monitor the application. we are running 4 applications on a single server. That can cause some profiling issue. Lets see if I can isolate this app. Do you see anything problematic with the current c3p0 config.

Comment: Why would 4 applications on a single server cause a profiling issue? There's no use in just looking at the c3p0 config, it's about as useful as using `top` to monitor a Java process.

Comment: You aren't actually using c3p0... You are using Commons DBCP regardless of what you have configured in hibernate. You are injecting the pre-configured `DataSource` into the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` basically rendering all `hibernate.c3p0` properties and other connection related settings for that matter useless (as it should as you configured an external datasource as is recommended by Hibernate and a lot of other resources).

Comment: @M.Deinum : I see it now with the bean dataSource. How can I override it and use c3p0 instead? Thank you.

Comment: Generally the issue isn't int he connection pool / `DataSource` configuration but how the large amount of data is being processed. Generally when doing processing of large amounts of data you want to periodically `flush` and `clear` the first level cache else it will eventually slow down everything.

Comment: @M.Deinum : After every new object is written in database, I am calling session.flush(), but not session.clear();

Comment: I would suggest using HikariCP instead of C3P0 and/or Commons DBCP. Next to that (as mentioned in my previous comment) your issue is probably not your datasource configuration but rather the way you are processing your data.

Comment: Don't call `flush` after each write (as that will slow down your application). Call after reasonable batches (preferably the same as you specified in your hibernate batch settings) like 50 or 100.

Comment: See https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-batch-insert-and-update-statements-with-hibernate/ for a good resource on how to do batch processing and configure hibernate for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters you aren't using C3P0 simply because you have configured the `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` as a `DataSource` and are injecting that into your `LocalSessionFactoryBean`. This basically renders all the `hibernate.c3p0` settings useless as they will be ignored.

Next you have issues with processing large amounts of data and I highly doubt the issue is your `DataSource` or connection pool but rather the way you are processing your entities and how you have configured Hibernate.

To speedup batch processing you want to flush every x records to the database and clear the first level cache. Why do you want to do this you might wonder. It has all to do with how Hibernate works, when you persist an entity what Hibernate does it will add it to the first level cache (the `Session` or `EntityManager`  in case of JPA). Each time you add an item to the first level cache it will do a dirty check on ALL of the entities in the first level cache to determine if something needs to be flushed. Now this will be fast for the first few entities but will become increasingly slower and slower.

Lets configure and code things for a batch size of 50.

First you want to configure hibernate to have a proper batch size and you want to order the insert and update statements. If you do this you can benefit from the fact that JDBC can now do a Batch Update (i.e. one insert or  update statement to modify 50 records instead of 50 single insert/update statement).

## Hibernate Configuration

```
<beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.ourapp.spring.model"/>
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</beans:prop>
               <!--<beans:prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">1000</beans:prop>-->
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.order_inserts">true</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</beans:prop>
            <!-- If you use versioned entities set this to true as well -->
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data">true<beans:prop> 
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

## Code Modification

```
public void yourLargeDataSetProcessingMethod() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    int i = 0;
    for (YourItem item : List<YourItem> items) {
        i++:
        // Here will be processing / creation

        if (i % 50 == 0) {
            session.flush();
            session.clear();
        }
    }
    session.flush();
    session.clear();
}
```

This will probably speed up your processing and database locking.

A final note, instead of Commons DBCP or C3P0 I would suggest to use [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) as the connection pool. It is very small and very fast and actively maintained (whereas C3P0 has been dormant for quite some time already).

[Here](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-batch-insert-and-update-statements-with-hibernate/) is a nice resource (with benchmarks etc.) on what each setting does and add or removes performance wise and how to configure things properly.

Comment: First, I am working on adding HikariCP. Once that is done. I will modify the code which is large to use batch processing. Lastly, if that doesn't help, will write native SQL queries instead of hibernate. I am getting an error when using HikariCP where Transactionmanager is complaining that bean must be of type sessionFactory. Can you please check this config : https://pastebin.com/xE0HSggC    . Thank you.

Comment: You should replace the `DataSource` NOT the `LocalSessionFactoryBean`. Only changing the datasource won't do much the real flaw is in the way you are processing the data.

Comment: Okay. Will change the datasource. I will make a new question for when done with modifying the processing code.

Comment: This worked nicely, the method is still slow, so I have posted a question in CodeReview. Can you please check out : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/191768/java-spring-hibernate-handling-large-and-multiple-objects-taking-a-long-time    Thank you. :-)

Comment: _Each time you add an item to the first level cache it will do a dirty check on ALL of the entities in the first level cache to determine if something needs to be flushed_ Why is the dirty check needed?